# logstash Authentication error with shield

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm getting the following error while trying to output data to elasticsearch from logstash:

> Failed to install template: [401]
>   {"error":"AuthenticationException[unable to authenticate user
>   [es_admin] for REST request [/_template/logstash]]","status":401}
>   {:level=>:error}

I have the configuration like this in logstash:

```
if [type]=="signup"{
            elasticsearch {
                    protocol => "http"
                    user =>"*****"
                    password =>"*******"
                    document_type => "signup"
                    host => "localhost"
                    index => "signups"
            }
    }
```

I have tried adding user with following commands:

`esusers useradd <username> -p <password> -r logstash`

I also tried giving role admin but logstash not working for admin user also.
The `localhost:9200` is asking for the password and after entering the password it works but the logstash is giving an error.

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar issue. There is a known issue with elasticsearch if the password has an "@" symbol, this issue can happen. See below link:

https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/issues/232

Also some documentation on elasticsearch has instructions to include "shield" configuration in elasticsearch.yml, but if you have only one shield realm, this is not needed. I dont have shield configuration in elasticsearch.yml

Answer (score 0):

I see that you tried with both logstash and admin user but failed.

To try with an admin privileged user:

Please make sure your /etc/elasticsearch/shield/roles.yml has below content for admin role:

```
# All cluster rights
# All operations on all indices
admin:
  cluster: all
  indices:
    '*':
      privileges: all
```

Then test something like below:

```
curl -u es_admin:es_admin_password localhost:9200/_cat/health
```

To make the **logstash role** user to work, logstash role need to be tweaked at roles.yml. I configured logstash to use *admin privileged user* to write to elasticsearch. I hope this would help.